# Google ReCaptcha - Missing input response

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I have a contact form and I want to avoid bots by using google recaptcha.  I am getting the error: missing-input-response and I do not why I think I am following the steps right. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" id="ContactForm" action="contact2.php">    
<input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name" id="name" >                       
<input placeholder="E-Mail" type="email" name="contactemail"  id="contactemail">            
<input placeholder="Organization Name" type="text" name="orgname" id="orgname" >
<input placeholder="Subject" type="text" name="sub" id="sub" class="StyleTxtField inputBg" style="background: url(images/subject.png) no-repeat left center; background-color:white; " required>
<textarea rows=5 cols=200 placeholder="Your e-mail" name="body" id="body" ></textarea>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."></div>
<span id="wrongcap" class="wrongInput">*Wrong !</span>

<button type="submit" id="button"  class="send">Send</button>       

</form>
```

and here how i check in contact2.php

```
    $url= 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey='...';
    $respnose= file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-respnose']);
    $data = json_decode($respnose);
    echo $respnose;
    echo "-1";
    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){
       echo "0";
    }else{
       echo "1";
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nop.. But if you are using laravel is a 2minutes proccess

Comment: Did you add
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`
on the contact form page?

Comment: @DanRoss thank you for your interest but I don't even know which website was the one that I was working on :p It was for training purposes

Comment: You misspelled response in your php code, maybe that's the problem